# From csv to multidimensional array (php)

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I would like go from:

```
A,A,A,A
A,A,A,B
A,A,B,A
A,A,B,B
A,B,A,A
A,B,A,B
A,B,B,A
A,B,B,B
B,A,A,A
B,A,A,B
B,A,B,A
B,A,B,B
B,B,A,A
B,B,A,B
B,B,B,A
B,B,B,B
```

to:

```
Array (
[A] => Array
    (
    [A] => Array
        (
        [A] => Array
            (
            [A] => A,
            [B] => B
        [B] => Array
            (
            [A] => A,
            [B] => B
    [B] => Array
        (
        [A] => Array
            (
            [A] => A,
            [B] => B
        [B] => Array
            (
            [A] => A,
            [B] => B
[B] => Array
    (
    [A] => Array
        (
        [A] => Array
            (
            [A] => A,
            [B] => B
        [B] => Array
            (
            [A] => A,
            [B] => B
    [B] => Array
        (
        [A] => Array
            (
            [A] => A,
            [B] => B
        [B] => Array
            (
            [A] => A,
            [B] => B
```

Comment: So what is the logic behind this transformation?

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that the number of A's in the first bit don't match up to the array. Also use the code formatting to make that array a bit easier to read.

Comment: You should provide a how this array is being built and then provide code that shows what you have attempted.

Comment: The starting list just shows binary counting from 0000 to 1111 with 0 1 replaced by A and B. Using this fact you can reproduce the data much simpler.

Comment: Did you give up or what?

Answer (score 1):

I'll probably regret this but I was bored.  Assuming you have a CSV file, if not then just `explode()` CSV string on `\n` or whatever:

```
$lines = file('/path/to/csv.txt');

$array = array();

foreach($lines as $line) {
    $temp  = &$array;

    $path  = str_getcsv($line);
    $value = array_pop($path);

    foreach($path as $key) {
        $temp =& $temp[$key];
    }
    $temp[$value] = $value;
}

print_r($array);
```

Comment: *I'll probably regret this* So why do you post it?

Comment: There's a chance that I won't ;-)  Worst case I delete it.

Comment: Also there is a change that some people don't really see what exactly you do with the references there so you might want to explain that + your answer does not contain `array_column` in it :P

Comment: @Rizier123 is "not enough array_column" the "not enough jquery" of PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your string to an array of rows by splitting on newlines.

Then loop over the rows and split on commas. The multidimensional array you want will be achieved by using each value from the CSV row as the key to a lower level in your result.

```
foreach (explode("\n", $csv_str) as $row) {
    $row = explode(',', $row);
    $result[$row[0]][$row[1]][$row[2]][$row[3]] = $row[3];
}
```

Comment: Nice if CSV is always known number of columns, in this case 4.

Comment: Thanks! Well, it would still _kind of_ work for CSVs with more than four columns, it would just ignore the rest of them. But yeah, fewer than four would be nokay.